# wordpress revolution slider refresh on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I have the rev slider on wordpress and only 1 slide - removed all links, but when I click on text anywhere or I'm selecting text, the page is refreshing.
this is the link: template-tuners.com - on homepage
How can I fix that? 
I can't find no links in source

Answer (score 0):

In your call to revolution api pass in this parameter - touchenabled: "off"

Answer (score -1):

remove link on your wordpress page section